# histogram is not created in R

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

It is the first time that I am using R since I need to create many plots for each file that I have.

I have a CSV file with four columns and I want to generate a histogram for each file and save it in a directory.
I could read the files and attach a data frame to them. but when I run, it seems the code stuck somewhere, neither generate Error nor the plots!
Data look like this

```
t1;w1;tt;probability
0;0.04745911973818716;reflections;0.0005
0;0.04745911973818716;clouds;0.001
0;0.04745911973818716;tree;0.14
```

Here is my code:

```
#list files
temp = list.files("myDirectory",pattern    ="*.csv")
path <- 
file.path("myDirectory")

for (i in 1:length(temp)){ 
  data <- read.csv(file.path(path, temp[i] ), sep = ";" )

  mypath <- file.path("C:","folder1","folder2","plots",paste("myplot_", i,".tiff", sep = "")) 
  tiff(file=mypath, width = 8, height = 8,units = 'in',res=300)

  hist(c(data$probabilities,data$words), breaks= 0:1, main="word probabilities",xlab="words")

  dev.off()
 }
```

Comment: Could you post an example of how the .csv files look? Just a subset should be ok, as long as they cause the same error.

Comment: `hist` (at least the base-R version) takes a single vector of values.  You are giving it two vectors of different types concatenated together, which it will probably convert to type character - and then your `breaks` statement is restricting the range to 0-1, so it is unlikely that it will plot anything.  Try just `hist(data$probabilities)`.

Comment: @AkselA: I updated

Comment: @AndrewGustar when I just give the probability as the only input, it generates a graph with the probability inX-axis and the frequency on the Y-axis. while I want the histogram shows the probabilities (y-axis) of the words (x-axis)

Comment: @Raha1986 probabilities vs words is not a histogram - you probably just need a `plot`

Comment: @AndrewGustar but the plot get the scattered points

Comment: @Raha1986 Perhaps you want `barplot`?

Comment: @AndrewGustar Actually I tried it, but since it is the first time I am working with R I could not get it work. I thought it is possible to give a type of plotting to have bars instead of points.

Comment: @Raha1986 using the data in your example, this might be what you are looking for... `barplot(df$probability,names.arg=df$tt)`

Comment: @AndrewGustar thanks, partly worked. there are bars which are higher than Y-axis

Comment: @Raha1986 Have a look at `?barplot` - there are lots of options to get it laid out the way you want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure what you really want is a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)?
If your .csv files contains more than a few dozen rows and you want to plot the distributions of probabilities, that's likely the case. If there are fewer rows, and you want to plot the probability of each individual word, you're likely looking for a barplot.
Just in case, here are examples of both. I simplified a few things to make it entirely self-contained.

First creating a directory named "so-test" and add a couple of .csv files to it.

```
dir.create(testdir <- "so-test")

write("t1;w1;tt;probability
       0;0.04745911973818716;reflections;0.05
       0;0.04745911973818716;clouds;0.02
       0;0.04745911973818716;tree;0.14", 
       file.path(testdir, "so-test1.csv"))

write("t1;w1;tt;probability
       0;0.04745911973818716;cramp;0.007
       0;0.04745911973818716;practice;0.009
       0;0.04745911973818716;brush;0.02",
       file.path(testdir, "so-test2.csv"))
```

Get a list of .csv files present in the directory

```
temp <- list.files(testdir, pattern=".csv$"); temp
path <- file.path(testdir)
```

Create a histogram over the probabilities.
It looks a bit weird as the number of probabilities is only three.

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
    data <- read.csv(file.path(path, temp[i]), sep = ";")

    mypath <- file.path(path, paste("hist_", i, ".png", sep=""))
    png(file=mypath, width=8, height=8, units='in', res=300)

    hist(data$probability, main="word probabilities",
      xlab="probability")

    dev.off()
}
```

[image]
[image]

Create a barplot displaying the probability associated with each word.

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
    data <- read.csv(file.path(path, temp[i]), sep = ";")

    mypath <- file.path(path, paste("barplot_", i, ".png", sep=""))
    png(file=mypath, width=8, height=8, units='in', res=300)

    barplot(data$probability, names.arg=data$tt, 
      main="word probabilities", ylab="probability")

    dev.off()
}
```

[image]
[image]